# change scene onEndOfMedia

Tags: java, javafx, media-player, media

is there a way to change the scene by `setOnEndOfMedia` in javafx ? .. i tried this but it's throwing a `NullPointerException`

```
void change(Event event){
        try{
            Node node=(Node) event.getSource();
            Stage   stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("astrolabe/astrolabe_intro.fxml"));/* Exception */

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");

            stage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

and calling `change()` on end of media like this

```
astrolabe_intro.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("tewst");
                Event e = new Event(null) ;
                e.fireEvent(astrolabe_intro1, e);
                change( e);


            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: On which line are you getting a `NullPointerException`? And can you give enough of your code, or at least an explanation, so we understand why you are trying to fire an event in the `onEndOfMedia` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the exception is coming from the `FXMLLoader.load(...)` line, the chances are that the path to the fxml file is wrong. Log the value of the URL you get from the call to `getResource(...)` to check.

But also:

Why do you need the event at all? The only place you use it in the `change` method is to get a node and get hold of the window. You presumably have other references to some nodes (I'm assuming this is a controller.) Why not just do

```
void change(){
        try{
            Node node= ... ;// any node in your scene will do....
            Stage   stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("astrolabe/astrolabe_intro.fxml"));/* Exception */

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");

            stage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

and then

```
astrolabe_intro.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        change();
    }
});
```

which in Java 8 you can abbreviate to

```
astrolabe_intro.setOnEndOfMedia(this::change);
```